# Create clusters from point layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatialite

There is a point layer with points in a irregular grid. I need to separate them in 11 more or less identical cluster so that each cluster has more ore less the same amount of points in one area. Is there a smart way in QGIS or SpatiaLite?

I need more or less the same amount of points in the clusters of points. That is not possible with k-means.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the clustering algorithms that are available in the QGIS *Processing toolbox* (*K-means clustering* and *DBSCAN clustering*)

Comment: I need more or less the same amount of points in the clusters of points. That is not possible with k-means.